# Custom View with Private Primary Constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

We have a Custom View through which we'd like to expose an API. In order not to clutter the View with logic, we'd like to pull the logic into separate classes and implement them through class delegation.

Consider this setup:

```
interface LoginFeatureCapabilities {
   fun login(): Boolean
}

class LoginFeatureImpl: LoginFeatureCapabilities {
   override fun login() = ...
}
```

We also have a custom view and would now like to delegate the `LoginFeatureCapabilities` to a `LoginFeatureImpl` instance while still being able to access it which means that we have to add it to the primary constructor:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    val loginFeatureImpl: LoginFeatureImpl = LoginFeatureImpl()
): View(context), LoginFeatureCapabilities by loginFeatureImpl
```

This causes the view to be null and the app to crash - there's no specific error in the logs though.

Adding a private constructor doesn't help either:

```
class CustomView private constructor(
    context: Context,
    val loginFeatureImpl: LoginFeatureImpl = LoginFeatureImpl()
): View(context), LoginFeatureCapabilities by loginFeatureImpl {

    @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, 
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ): this(context, LoginFeatureImpl())

}
```

Is it possible to keep a reference of the instance that is being delegated to in a Custom View?

Comment: You should set the property as a lateinit var instead of trying to force it in the constructor; Android uses reflection out of the box to build views, so unless you are also setting a LayoutInflater.Factory, you should probably use a setter.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I need to access the `LoginFeatureImpl` instance later on, so it has to be defined in the primary constructor (there are some limitations to how class delegation currently works in Kotlin) as members can't be referenced when delegating.

Comment: "This causes the view to be null and the app to crash" Nope, this is not the cause. After finding a stack trace, you will find out that the whole question is incorrect.

Comment: Well, this would most likely work only if you set a LayoutInflater.Factory